# Individual column searching text input angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-pipe

> I am looking for an individual column search on the data table and I
> have already been used a common search bar using pipe now I have to
> implement proper functionality for search by each column i.e. search
> by ID, search by name, Search by age, and so on. It would be very
> helpful if anyone can help me with this.
>
> app.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
        <div>
            <h1>Nested Array Table</h1>
            <div class="md-form">
                <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchText" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Search" />
            </div>
        
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    
                    <tr>
                        <th>#ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Weight</th>
                        <th>Height</th>
                        <th>Mobile</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th><input type="text" id="search id" placeholder="Search by ID" /></th>
                        <th><input type="text" id="search name" placeholder="Search by Name" /></th>
                        <th><input type="text" id="search age" placeholder="Search by Age" /></th>
                        <th><input type="text" id="search weight" placeholder="Search by Weight" /></th>
                        <th><input type="text" id="search height" placeholder="Search by Height" /></th>
                        <th><input type="text" id="search mobile" placeholder="Search by Mobile" /></th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>
                    <tr
                        *ngFor="let item of ItemsArray| FilterPipe: 
                        {name: searchText, age:searchText, weight: searchText, height:searchText, mobile: searchText}; let i=index;">
                        <td>{{ i+1 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
                        <th>{{ item.data.age }}</th>
                        <td>{{ item.data.weight }}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.data.height}}</td>
                        <td>{{ item.data.mobile }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

> app.ts

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'testJobNestedArray';
    searchableList: any;
    public searchText : string;
    public ItemsArray : any;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.ItemsArray = [
            {
                name: 'manpreet',
                data:{
                        age: 25,
                        weight: 65,
                        height: 5.6,
                        mobile: [9780698969, 6895741258]
                    }   
            },
            {
                name: 'abdul',
                data: {
                        age: 26,
                        weight: 80,
                        height: 6.0,
                        mobile: [3698541258]
                    }
            },
            {
                name: 'onkar',
                data: {
                        age: 28,
                        weight: 70,
                        height: 5.8,
                        mobile: [8569741236, 6528965478]
                    }
            }
        ]
        // this.searchableList = ['name', 'age', 'weight', 'height', 'mobile']
        console.log('this.ItemsArray', this.ItemsArray)
    }
}
```

> pipe.ts

```
 import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'FilterPipe',
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {


    transform(items: any, filter: any, defaultFilter: boolean): any {
        if (!filter || !Array.isArray(items)) {
            return items;
        }

        if (filter && Array.isArray(items)) {
            let filterKeys = Object.keys(filter);

            if (defaultFilter) {
                return items.filter(item =>
                    filterKeys.reduce((x, keyName) =>
                        (x && new RegExp(filter[keyName], 'gi').test(item[keyName])) || filter[keyName] == "", true));
            }
            else {
                return items.filter(item => {
                    return filterKeys.some((keyName) => {
                        console.log(filter[keyName])
                        return new RegExp(filter[keyName], 'gi').test(item[keyName]) || 
                        new RegExp(filter[keyName], 'gi').test(item.data[keyName]) ||
                        filter[keyName] == "";
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is using an object to make the filters, you can pass the object to the `pipe` call and make your filters there.

In your `app.ts`:

```
export class AppComponent {
    filterObject: {fullSearch: string, id: number, name: string, age: number, weight: number, height: number, mobile: string} = {
        fullSearch: null,
        id: null,
        name: null,
        age: null,
        weight: null,
        height: null,
        mobile: null
    }
```

in your `app.html`:

```
  <div class="md-form">
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filterObject.fullSearch" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
  </div>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filterObject.id"  placeholder="Search by ID" /></th>
        <th><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filterObject.name" placeholder="Search by Name" /></th>
        <th><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filterObject.age" placeholder="Search by Age" /></th>
        <th><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filterObject.weight" placeholder="Search by Weight" /></th>
        <th><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filterObject.height" placeholder="Search by Height" /></th>
        <th><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filterObject.mobile" placeholder="Search by Mobile" /></th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody>
<tr
    *ngFor="let item of ItemsArray| FilterPipe: filterObject; let i=index;">
    <td>{{ i+1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
    <th>{{ item.data.age }}</th>
    <td>{{ item.data.weight }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.data.height}}</td>
    <td>{{ item.data.mobile }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I really appreciate it, and thanks for your suggestion. Actually, I am looking for an individual column to be filtered and the main search bar is already working with the pipe concept now I need to be filtered or search data according to the columns. As you can see Search by ID, Search by Name and so on.

Comment: What I posted is exactly the response you wrote

Comment: I made an edit to achieve both ways, search global or individual

Answer (score 0):

I think it worth trying Ag grid, It is powered with many features like column filter and good performance you can customize it as well .[Ag Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php)